# Check for null WebResponseObject

Tags: powershell, null, webrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm storing the response of an Invoke-WebRequest command in a variable:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -Body $body -Headers $headers -Method POST
```

The API I'm hitting will return null if the processing I'm doing is complete, and I need to check for it:

```
PS C:\Users\me> Write-Host $response
null
```

I've tried all the following tests:

```
If (!$response) {
    Write-Host 'Null 1.'
}
If ($response -eq 'null') {
    Write-Host 'Null 2.'
}
If ($response -eq $null) {
    Write-Host 'Null 3.'
}
If ($response -eq [string]::Empty) {
    Write-Host 'Null 4.'
}
If ($null -eq $response) {
    Write-Host 'Null 5.'
}
```

None of these work. I know the empty string was a long shot but I figured one of the others should work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is it possible there's a blank character being returned with the null? Maybe try something like `$response -like "*null*"` to check that.

Comment: Your web API is literally returning the word `null` not an empty string or the `$null` character.

Comment: @Nick that did it - I tested for 'null' and made sure it was only 4 characters (to my eyes), but there must be a blank character in there somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: `$response -like "*null*"` can give false positives if `null` appears on any part of the response.

Comment: Whoever downvoted, can you explain why? I asked the question clearly and explained what I had tried, if there's something I did wrong I'd love to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$response` object is a `WebResponseObject` (or a class that derives from it) and it holds more than just content of a response. That's why the equality checks are failing.

```
PS C:\Users\me> Write-Host $response
```

prints `null` because `Write-Host` calls `ToString()` on the `$response` object behind the scenes, which returns `Content` property. Corresponding [ToString() implementation is here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/c3ac21bbaf3d270cc80e372d8613b2b3801b259a/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/WebCmdlet/Common/WebResponseObject.Common.cs).

So the following should work if there is no hidden characters in the response:

```
If ($response.Content -eq "null")
{
  Write-Host "Server returned null"
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I was missing, thanks Mustafa.